# Is it possible to send data over intent in Sony SmallApplication

Tags: android, android-intent, sony

I'm trying to start a `SmallApplication` with parameters, using `Intent`.

MainActivity:

```
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SmallApplicationSample.class);
    i.putExtra("title", "Title of SmallApp");
    i.putExtra("value", 32);
    SmallApplicationManager.startApplication(MainActivity.this, i);
```

SmallApplicationSample/onCreate:

```
    Intent i = getIntent();
    String title = i.getStringExtra("title"); // NullPointerExeption
    int value = i.getIntExtra("value", 0);
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible.

From Small App v2 API, we have SmallApplication.getIntent() API.
http://developer.sonymobile.com/reference/sony-addon-sdk/com/sony/smallapp/SmallApplication#getIntent%28%29

Like android’s standard Activity.getIntent() API, we can get passed intent parameters using SmallApplication.getIntent() API. It’s very similar to implementation for Activity.
As described in API document, this API should be used after onStart() called. Cannot be used in onCreate() method.